# Lead convert choose existing radio button

Tags: apex, visualforce, lead-conversion

In Lead Convert [image]

how to find programmatically in apex trigger if the `Choose Existing` is selected or if `CREATE NEW` option is selected?

Thanks

Comment: In what sense? In a trigger? A component? Something else? It's not clear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In apex trigger. As soon as the user select the `choose existing` radio button option I need to be able to capture that action. How I can achieve that?

Comment: Trigger is only fired when you perform a DML, not sure what you are trying to do, its a standard screen, for any changes you need to create your own page/component to replicate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you select any existing Account/Contact/Opportunity when converting Lead, the field ConvertedAccountId/ConvertedContactId/ConvertedOpportunityId will be populated by EXISTING Account Id/Contact Id/Opportunity Id.

See the lead fields reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Lead.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried with both options EXISTING and CREATE NEW. However in CREATE NEW ConvertedContactId is also existing and is not blank. Is there a way to find programmatically in apex trigger if EXISTING is selected or if CREATE NEW option is selected?